# lftp install unsuccessful

Tags: perl, installation, centos, centos6, lftp

I try to install lftp on our CentOS 6 server.

First I tried this:

```
yum install lftp
```

But I got: "No package lftp available"

Second I downloaded rpm and tried to install it.

```
rpm -Uvh /root/src2/lftp-4.3.8-1.el6.rfx.x86_64.rpm
```

I got:
"error: Failed dependencies:
    perl(String::CRC32) is needed by lftp-4.3.8-1.el6.rfx.x86_64"

I tried to resolve this by:

```
perl -MCPAN -e shell
```

and

```
install String::CRC32
```

(There was another issue, but I could solve it with installing YAML modul too)

Finally it was successful.

List of installed modules now (instmodsh):
    Installed modules are:
       ExtUtils::MakeMaker
       Geography::Countries
       IP::Country
       Mail::SPF
       Mail::SpamAssassin
       Net::DNS::Resolver::Programmable
       Perl
       String::CRC32
       YAML
       razor-agents

If I try to rerun rpm install, I got the same error message.
"error: Failed dependencies:
    perl(String::CRC32) is needed by lftp-4.3.8-1.el6.rfx.x86_64"

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dependency must be met by installing the pre-packaged version of String::CRC32. For CentOS 6, this appears to be perl-String-CRC32-1.4-9.el6.x86_64.rpm (your available package may have a different version number).

Comment: I don't understand exactly, but it works with 'yum install perl-String-CRC32'. Thank you very much!